# How to create csv with header and footer using LinqtoCsv or anything better in C#

Tags: c#, linqtocsv

I am trying to export data in csv format. I am using LinqToCsv to create csv. Is it possible to create footer section using LinqToCsv?

Can anyone help me how to create a csv with header and footer using LinqToCsv or with anything else using C#?

I need something to create csv of following format:

```
Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|Column 4|Column 5
--- data goes here
---
Trailer: test | 1231312 | xxx
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) for this example.

```
class TempRecord
{
    public string FirstCol { get; set; }
    public string LastCol { get; set; }
}
class FooterRecord
{
    public string FooterText { get; set; }        
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tempRecords = new List<TempRecord>();
        tempRecords.Add(new TempRecord{FirstCol = "row1a", LastCol="row1z"});
        tempRecords.Add(new TempRecord{FirstCol = "row2a", LastCol="row2z"});

        var outputCsv = @"M:\temp\temp.csv";            
        using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText(outputCsv))
        {
            var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
            csv.WriteRecords(tempRecords);
            csv.WriteRecord(new FooterRecord { FooterText = "Hey! THis is a footer" });
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the output csv file:

[image]